# Entity / mysql table referencing to multiple other tables ORM Symfony2

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

is there any good way to handle entity referencing to multiple tables using `Symfony 2` and `doctrine 2` ?

I want to implement tags system. Thus, I was planning to create entity (and  mySQL table) called tags looking like this:

```
field: id
field: item kind - value of this field should reference to one of entity types (mysql tables) already defined
field: item id - which will reference to given entity id in [item kind] table
field: tag name - simple text field
```

Normally I define relationship like this:

```
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Books", inversedBy="items")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="book", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
```

In this case using normal mySQL query I would do the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM tags WHERE item kind = '[entity type/name]' AND item id = '[entity id]'
```

How should I define relationship in this case so that symfony2 and doctrine2 knows what to do? Is this even possible?

Comment: It's a sql limitation that makes it challenging for one column to reference multiple tables.  You could use doctrine's table inheritance http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance.  Each of your taggable entities would inherit from a base taggable table.  Your tag entity would then point to the taggable table.  There are some limits but it can be made to work.

Comment: The given concept seems ok, however as I understand it works only as long as each entity I have one field with such a relationship. In other words I can't make system which references to two separate "tags" tables. Am I right?